# Why do these inline-block divs not fit inside their container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark0978/yPPbA/1/) is a result of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732240/does-angular-have-a-flex-layout-like-extjs).  In it, I have a 3 div flexbox and a 4 div flexbox.  (At this moment, it has nothing to do with Angular)

Ideally the flex divs would fit inside their container, but even though they are collectively narrower than their container, they don't fit (one div is pushed out).  More confusing is that they are off by different amounts.

When there are 4 divs, the sum of the widths of the 4 is 814px, while the container is 819px wide.  If I shrink the width of the widest div by 9 pixels, making the total width 804, they all fit within their container as expected.

```
#hbox1: width is 819, inner is 819, outer is 821
0 Object {borderWidth: 0, marginWidth: 0, paddingWidth: 0, flex: 1,
1 Object {borderWidth: 2, marginWidth: 0, paddingWidth: 0, flex: 2,
2 Object {borderWidth: 0, marginWidth: 0, paddingWidth: 0, flex: 1,
3 Object {borderWidth: 0, marginWidth: 0, paddingWidth: 0, flex: 1,
#hbox1 finalFlexTotal is 814
```

When there are 3 divs, I have to shrink the width of the widest div by 6 pixels to make them all fit in their container.

```
#hbox2: width is 819, inner is 819, outer is 821
0 Object {borderWidth: 0, marginWidth: 0, paddingWidth: 0, flex: 1,
1 Object {borderWidth: 2, marginWidth: 0, paddingWidth: 0, flex: 2,
2 Object {borderWidth: 0, marginWidth: 0, paddingWidth: 0, flex: 1,
#hbox2 finalFlexTotal is 815
```

I've accounted for borderWidth, and marginWidth and paddingWidth are 0.  Why don't the div's fit in their container without some kind of random adjustment?

Here is the code and html in case the fiddle goes away:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="hbox1" style="border: 1px solid red">
    <div flex=1 style="display:inline-block;height:100%">This is the A Box</div>
    <div flex=2 style="border:1px solid black;display:inline-block;height:100%">This is the B Box</div>
    <div flex=1 style="display:inline-block;height:100%">This is the C Box</div>
    <div flex=1 style="display:inline-block;height:100%">This is the D Box</div>
</div>
<div id="hbox2" style="border: 1px solid red;margin-top:40px">
    <div flex=1 style="display:inline-block;height:100%">This is the A Box</div>
    <div flex=2 style="border:1px solid black;display:inline-block;height:100%">This is the B Box</div>
    <div flex=1 style="display:inline-block;height:100%">This is the C Box</div>
</div><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function flexBoxIt(selector) {
    var $node,
    index,
    flexValue,
    flexInfo = [],
        totalFlex = 0,
        finalFlexTotal = 0;

    $(selector).children('div').each(function (index) {
        $node = $(this);
        flexValue = $node.attr("flex");
        flexValue = flexValue ? parseInt(flexValue, 10) : 1,
        flexInfo[index] = {
            "borderWidth": parseInt($node.css('borderLeftWidth'), 10) + parseInt($node.css('borderRightWidth'), 10),
            "marginWidth": parseInt($node.css('marginLeft'), 10) + parseInt($node.css('marginRight'), 10),
            "paddingWidth": parseInt($node.css('paddingLeft'), 10) + parseInt($node.css('paddingRight'), 10),
            "flex": flexValue,
            "$jq": $node
        };
        totalFlex += flexValue;
    });
    width = $(selector).width();
    console.log("%s: width is %d, inner is %d, outer is %d", selector, width, $(selector).innerWidth(), $(selector).outerWidth(true));
    for (index in flexInfo) {
        node = flexInfo[index];
        node.width = Math.floor(width * node.flex / totalFlex - node.borderWidth);
        finalFlexTotal += node.width;
        console.log(index, node);
        node.$jq.css("width", node.width + "px");
    }
    console.log("%s finalFlexTotal is %d", selector, finalFlexTotal);
}

flexBoxIt("#hbox1");
flexBoxIt("#hbox2");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space between the elements cause extra width. You need to put all your elements on one line, like this:

```
<div flex=1 style="...">This is the A Bo</div><div ...>This is the B Box</div>...
```

Comment: Wow, I never even suspected that!

Answer (score 1):

basically, its because of white-space in your markup (new lines are treated as white space in `inline-block` elements). they are causing an extra space.

there is a grate [article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) aboute how to fight the space between `inline-block` elements, you have a lot of different solutions.

Comment: Yes, that is a very good article about the problem and numerous ways to solve it.